# Search_Service_Application_DB permissions

Tags: search, user-profile-service, enterprise-search

All of the sudden no one can get to their profiles in our SharePoint 2010 Enterprise environment. A lovely unexpected error message pops up. Comparing the correlation ID with the ULS logs, it appears that the web application pool account is trying to access the Search_Service_Application_DB_GUID db. It has never needed this before, and clearly doesn't have it now. Any ideas as to why it's trying to use this account? Does anybody have their web application pool account with any permissions on this db?

Comment: App Pool does not required the access to the Search DB Unless you have same account for search services and Web App Pool. Also could you please share the ULS logs trace for the correlation ID....Also try to dis associate the Search services from the web App and then try? What about the User Profile Services, up and running and having the proper permission with web app etc?

Comment: Yeah, that is completely my understanding as well.  Each service application/webapp/etc. has it's own service account.  

Here's the ULS trace for that correlation ID.

http://textuploader.com/rev6

Some SS's of the services and accounts:

http://imgur.com/x5n3QOY

Comment: All the Screenies...
http://imgur.com/a/Sw6rA

Comment: So, I tried disassociating the search service from the web app, and it worked just fine.  As soon as I re-associated it, it failed again.  Seems like something is jacked with that service.  May be best to rebuild it...

Comment: do you have any customization on the search services? also check from IIS under which account Search Services App pool running? do you have the search center in the same web app where you have the issue?

Comment: No customization on the search services, that I can think of off the top of my head.  IIS matches the app pool with the account that is set in central administration.  The search center is in the same web app that is having the issue, but another web app that is associated with the search service (however the search center isn't set there), also exhibits the same issue.

Comment: this is typical sitution with User Profile Services but search i never heard this...i think give the app. check under which app pool search admin site is running....check this article http://akhileshnirapure.blogspot.com/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-service-account.html

Comment: All of that was fine.  What is odd to me is that it's trying to hit the admin database, not the crawl database.  Administration Database : Search_Service_Application_DB_cbc291cd21fe409f8446f11be8c4dc9e.  Another workaround was to give the web application pool account db_owner on that db...but I don't like that much.  I'll probably just end up rebuilding the search application service when I get a chance.  Thanks for your help in trying to diagnose this!